# Routing Template results in a 404 when navigating to English /en/ site

Tags: .net-core, routes

I have one basic routing template on my newly created project (.NET Core 2.2) (below).

```
routes.MapRoute(
  name: "default",
  template: "{parameter}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
);
```

If I try to go to `localhost:5000/en/default/index` it is **not working** (I get a 404). Something except "en" is working properly like `localhost:5000/abc/default/index` or `localhost:5000/xyz/default/index`.

Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to run my web app on IIS Express, it automatically adds configuration to `applicationhost.config` which is located at `{SolutionFolder}\\.vs\\{SolutionName}\\config\\applicationhost.config`. And it has virtual directories starting with "/en/". I don't know why IIS Express adds this virtual directories but that was the actual redirection problem.